# delete data in firebase React

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem with delete a data in firebase with react , Can you help me ? [Firebase my class component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yorjq.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 0):

In the image provided the issue isn't shown. The only thing shown is your function that pushes to firebase. But try using something like this

```
firebase.database().ref(`Transactions/+transactionUID`).remove(item)
```